# Run bash script upon ssh

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, ssh

I have a host on which I created a script .

The script is being executed whenever the user is logging in via ssh bashrc launches the script.

Now I'm trying to get the script to execute even if the user is not actually logging in , and just running a command . 
For example I want the script to be executed if a user is running the following :

```
ssh user@host.com some_command
```

Is there a way to achieve the above?

Comment: so what's the problem with the above approach? you can run commands like "ssh user@host  '/path/to/script.sh'" if you have everything (permissions) configured correctly.

Comment: I guess that he wants a script being executed on the remote host when the user runs a script via `ssh` not only when the user logs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution affecting all the users could be using `pam-exec` and launch a script on the user login event. Check the [pam-exec manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec) and an example on how to use it [pam-exec scripting](http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html).

A simple solution for a single user should be add the script in the `rc` file of the `ssh` user, add your script to:

```
~/.ssh/rc
```

I've done some tests and the `rc` solution works fine in your case, it gets executed when the user launches a remote command via `ssh`.

If you don't have a `rc` file just create it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but what if I don't have an rc file under ~/ssh dir ?  btw this is a win host running cygwin

Comment: You're welcome, if you find my answer helpful please upvote and/or accept it. If you don't have the `rc` file just create it in the `~/.ssh/`.

Comment: when I create it , what should be writen inside ? '!/bin/bash ./script_name' ? or something else?

Comment: You have 2 possibilities: or the full script or a call to your script.

Comment: Nice! If you find my answer helpful please upvote and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can edit authorized_keys file and add a COMMAND , something like :
command="/home/michale/bin/dothis.sh" ...public key...
for more details read ssh and authorized_keys documentations.